# How to get alert list of context or context mask for certain time in AggreGate events

Tags: iot

I'm trying to get a history of all alerts on a single device using the expression:

`callFunction("events","get","users.admin.alerts.*","alert","dc()=='users.admin.models.device1'&&({env/level}==4||{env/level}==3)",dateAdd(date(year(now()),month(now()),day(now()),-3,0,0),(dayOfWeek(now())==1?-6:((dayOfWeek(now())-2)*-1)),"d"), now())`

But I get an empty result. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly specified the context field in the expression condition

```
callFunction("events","get","users.admin.alerts.*","alert","{context}=='users.admin.models.device1'&&({env/level}==4||{env/level}==3)",dateAdd(date(year(now()),month(now()),day(now()),-3,0,0),(dayOfWeek(now())==1?-6:((dayOfWeek(now())-2)*-1)),"d"), now())
```